# if in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, workbench

I was trying to do this query but I found a problem with IF statement, I also tried to insert delimiter or begin and else but it does not work the same.

how can I project different queries depending on the value of a variable?

```
  create or replace view PazientiTarget as
select P.CodFiscale
from Paziente P INNER JOIN Esordio E ON E.Paziente=P.CodFiscale
NATURAL JOIN Terapia T
where E.Patologia='Ipertensione'
    and E.Cronica='si'
    and E.DataGuarigione is null
    and E.DataEsordio + interval 10 year < current_date()
group by T.Paziente,T.Farmaco
having count(distinct T.Farmaco)<=2;

create or replace view Appoggio as
select T.Farmaco,T.Patologia,count(distinct T.Paziente) as Numero
from Terapia T NATURAL JOIN Esordio E inner join Patologia PA on PA.Nome=E.Patologia
where T.Paziente in (select PT.CodFiscale
                     from PazientiTarget PT)
and T.Patologia<>'Ipertensione'
and PA.ParteCorpo='Cuore'
and E.Cronica='si'
group by T.Farmaco,T.Patologia;

set @controllo=( select count(*)
             FROM Appoggio A
             where A.Numero=(select max(A1.Numero)
                           from Appoggio A1));


if @controllo > 1 then
    select*
    from Appoggio A
    limit 0;



else

select*
from Appoggio A
where A.Numero=(select max(A1.Numero)
                from Appoggio A1
                where A.Farmaco<>A1.Farmaco); 

end if;
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: MYSQL supports this kind of `if` only for stored procedures ([see this if docs here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php#MIF)). There is another kind of `if` you can use in requests, for values retreiving only, [see here for docs](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php)

Comment: thanks for the answer, so how can I change the code?

Comment: Put it in a procedure.